# Hide column filtering or formatting buttons

Tags: jasperserver, visualize

Is it possible to hide any of the individual Jive buttons in Visualize.js?

I.e. column filtering or formatting?

I looked at the API, and it doesn't appear to be documented. As a worst case approach, I'm investigating hiding the buttons via CSS.

Comment: If you want to disable all report interactivity with Visualize.js, you can pass `defaultJiveUi:{enabled: false}` in the `report` call.  See https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-visualizejs-guide/v62/api-usage-interactive-reports#Disabling_the_JIVE_UI

Comment: It seems that the link in my previous comment pointed to an old version of the docs, you can go here for the latest version https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-visualizejs-guide/v750/api-usage-interactive-reports#Disabling_the_JIVE_UI

Comment: I updated my verbiage to say 'hide individual buttons' instead of 'disable'. I was thinking that it were synonymous, but your link shows that it is not. It is a strange experience to show all buttons but have them disabled IMHO. Thank you though! @dad67